# Meaning of the spectral norm of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

Is there an intuitive meaning for the [spectral norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html) of a matrix? Why would an algorithm calculate the relative recovery in spectral norm between two images (i.e. one before the algorithm and the other after)? Thanks

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The spectral norm (also know as Induced 2-norm) is the maximum singular value of a matrix. Intuitively, you can think of it as the maximum 'scale', by which the matrix can 'stretch' a vector.

The maximum singular value is the square root of the maximum eigenvalue or the maximum  eigenvalue if the matrix is symmetric/hermitian

Comment: thanks - this helps me conceptually.

Comment: This is specifically important since noise will be amplified by this value. For a very nice and intuitive understanding of this I recommend slides 21 and 22 of http://ee263.stanford.edu/lectures.html .

Comment: @divB, of which lecture?

Comment: 27, "SVD and applications"

Comment: This is only true for symmetric matrices. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437569/do-eigenvectors-correspond-to-direction-of-maximum-scaling#comment7397070_1437569

Comment: It is also noted there that $A^TA$ provides a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 28):

Let us consider the singular value decomposition (SVD) of a matrix $X = U S V^T$, where $U$ and $V$ are matrices containing the left and right singular vectors of $X$ in their columns. $S$ is a diagonal matrix containing the singular values. A intuitive way to think of the norm of $X$ is in terms of the norm of the singular value vector in the diagonal of $S$. This is because the singular values measure the *energy* of the matrix in various principal directions.

One can now extend the $p$-norm for a finite-dimensional vector to a $m\times n$ matrix by working on this singular value vector:

\begin{align}
\|X\|_p &=  \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\text{min}(m,n)} \sigma_i^p \right)^{1/p}
\end{align}

This is called the *Schatten norm* of $X$. Specific choices of $p$ yield commonly used matrix norms:

1. $p=0$: Gives the rank of the matrix (number of non-zero singular values).
2. $p=1$: Gives the nuclear norm (sum of absolute singular values). This is the tightest convex relaxation of the rank.
3. $p=2$: Gives the Frobenius norm (square root of the sum of squares of singular values).
4. $p=\infty$: Gives the spectral norm (max. singular value).

Comment: thanks - can we really talk about Schatten p=0 for matrices? since we would be looking at 1/0...?

Comment: Yes we can. And it is equal to the rank of the matrix. Can you clarify your question a bit more?

Comment: Hi - i was referring to the Schatten norm equation above: the exponent is 1/p. If p=0 we have 1/0. thanks.. p must > 1.

Comment: Think of $p \rightarrow 0$. Then any nonzero singular values will lead to $1$, while $0$ singular values will give $0$ anyway. Hence, you will end up with the number of non-zero singular values. However, for $p \in [0,1]$, the Schatten norm is not a "norm" since it does not satisfy all the properties. However, it is still common practice to call it a "norm".

Comment: ok, i understand better - thanks again.

Comment: I just want to point out the confusion in your notation, the same notation: $||A||_2$ is also being used as spectral norm of a Matrix, which is the $p=\infty$ in your answer. I don't know what is Schatten Norm but one thing is universally agreed is that, matrix is an operator, and its norm should be defined in an operator fashion.

Comment: Please clear up the notations to be consistent with the literature, wikipedia for example.