# do eigenvectors correspond to direction of maximum scaling?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does the eigenvector correspond to a direction in which maximum scaling occurs by a given transformation matrix (A) acting upon this vector.
I quote from : 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243553

> No other vector when acted by this matrix will get stretched as much
>   as this eigenvector.

Is the above statement always true?... For example let 
$$
A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0.578385540014544 & 0.703045745965410 \\
0.477513363789115 & 0.922698950982510 \\
 \end{array} \right) 
$$

The largest eigenvalue is 1.35 (approx.)

Now, consider the vector (not eigenvector)
$$
v = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-0.538656963091298 \\
-0.842525178326001 \\
 \end{array} \right) 
$$

magnitude(v) = 1.0

magnitude(A*v) = 1.373

So this vector(v), which is not the eigenvector of A is scaled by a larger amount (x1.373), compared to the eigenvector which is scaled by x 1.35 (approx.)

Is this just an artifact of numerical precision ? I can easily create more examples of random square transformation matrices (A) where the eigenvector does not correspond to the direction of maximum scaling.

Comment: The quote is a false statement. It is true for a *symmetric* matrix that the largest eigenvalue (in absolute value) equals the largest stretch factor. Your example shows that it's not necessarily true in general.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Greg.

Comment: Hey @GregMartin can you point me to any prove for your statement that it is true only for a symmetric matrix?

Comment: What was the magnitude of the original eigenvector?

Comment: And so, do we have any ultimate useful result for when A is not symmetric?

Comment: Thanks, this was a great question that really helped me understand that the spectral radius is larger than or equal to the largest eigenvalue, with equality only occurring when the matrix is symmetric

Answer (score 6):

There is something called the matrix norm, $||A||$ which according to *Linear Algebra and it's Applications* by Strang is defined on $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ to be $$||A||=\max_{x\neq0}\frac{||Ax||}{||x||},$$
where $||x||=\sqrt{x^Tx}$. From this, $||Ax||\le||A||||x||$. So the norm measures the "amplifying effect" of $A$ on a vector $x$. Equality happens at the optimal $x$. The value $||Ax||/||x||$ is always nonnegative. We square this to get
$$||A||^2=\max_{x\neq0}\frac{x^TA^TAx}{x^Tx}.$$
Matrix $A^TA$ is symmetric. This is known as the Rayleigh quotient, as it is well known that its maximum is attained when $x$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. Then the maximum happens when $x$ is the eigenvector of $A^TA$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of that matrix.

Answer (score 3):

No - An eigenvector is the "input vector" of a matrix that "outputs" a vector in the same direction. If you really want an intuitive understanding of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors, follow the link. (I don't have the reputation needed to post images.)

[Linear Transformations & Eigenvectors Explained](http://www.austinadee.com/index.php/2015/06/06/linear-transforms-and-eigenvectors/)