# Meaning of the spectral metric on matrices?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-norm

Let $|A|$ be the spectral norm of a matrix $A$. The intuition for it is the maximum "stretch" it can do to a vector. (see e.g. [Meaning of the spectral norm of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188202/meaning-of-the-spectral-norm-of-a-matrix))

Consider the metric $d(A,B)=|A-B|$. Is there a similar intuition for what this says about matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: The spectral norm **is** the induced metric (corresponding to the Eulcidean norm)

Comment: okay. sorry for being imprecise. I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Question is clear now, thank you